# How to change border color of this image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects

I have a button image in a PSD file. The image is in single layer.

[image]

I want to change the color of the border to a bright green color.

How do I do that in Photoshop?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing how the psd id constructed it's difficult to say. Is the single layer a rasterized layer? A Shape Layer? A smart Object layer?

Comment: You could easily ruin it by trying to color that border. I would definitely remake the whole button considering that it could basically be made with 2 shapes, 1 dropshadow and 2 different (and rather simple) gradients.

Comment: I agree that starting from scratch would actually be the fastest. Then you could also fix the border radius which is incorrect. If you *must* use this file, measure the radius and make a mask from two rounded rectangles with the measured radii.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a newbie here. Can you please tell me know to recreate this button. I am not sure how to have the dark color shade at the lower portion of this button..and also how to add the border. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The darker part is a result of a gradient. the border probably best to be done in layerstyles, same for the drop shadow. I suggest you google for some tutorials to get a basic knowledge of photoshop first.

Comment: I took a closer look at your button. The right border is misaligned completely which makes coloring impossible. You really have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of the problem I have adressed (repeatedly) in the comments, which I believe to be the biggest issue for recoloring:

[image]

I still think recreating the rounded rectangle plus adding border is the best way to go. The original gradient can still be used as a texture for the button. Only the drop shadow has to be recreated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people are telling you it can't be recolored because it can be. The quality of the image and its alignment has nothing to do with whether or not it can be recolored.

1. Select the inside square.
2. Shift+Select (add a second selection) for the area completely outside of the shape
3. Inverse selection - now only the outter border should be selected
4. Copy+Paste so that the border is duplicated onto its own layer
5. Layer > Style > Color or Gradient Overlay depending on what you're trying to do.

To answer how the dark color shade happened in the lower portion of this button it by using Bevel/Emboss options on probably a duplicated layer so that the original creator had more control over the opacity. That is found by creating say a rounded rectangle as in this example and going to layer > style> bevel/emboss.

Comment: If you look closely, the right border of the button is misaligned, resulting in an outline that never meets. Making a "border" impossible.

Comment: I know what you're referring to but there is clearly still a border. Whether it is a good border or a border that meets your expectations of a border is irrelevant to the question of how to change its color.

Comment: Yes there still is a border. But it has a "step", unfortunately exactly where the color of the button and the border are the same. So one would have to make a guess where to make this step in recoloring or design some sort of transition. That's why "select the inside square" won't work because it will either cut off part of the button or leave part of the border in its original color.

Comment: the misalignment would be really easy to fix with a simple copy-paste action. really, all the drama is unnecessary.